# Fricked up my under-arm joint topogroaphy

Tags: topology

It has a really wierd shape and I'n not sure how I messed it up this bad. I could have solved it if i didn't apply the subdiv modifier for sculpting. Basically looking for any idea or possible solution. Feel free to answer whatever you feel like could save the joint so I can look forward on having it animated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it by selecting the edge loop before the joint, hiding it and deleting the whole arm and rebuilding it from those vertices by extending it.